# how to propagate the trace_id within the Java Stream API in Spring Cloud Zipkin

Tags: java, spring, zipkin

I would like to know how to propagate the trace_id within the Java Stream API in Spring Cloud Zipkin.

In the code below, the trace_id is not propagated, and each client ends up having an individual trace_id.

```java
TestForkJoinPool testForkJoinPool = new TestForkJoinPool(10);
Span span = tracer.nextSpan(tracer.currentSpan());

testForkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
    try (SpanInScope ignored = tracer.withSpan(span)) {
        IntStream.range(1, 20).parallel().forEach(idx -> {
            client.get(1000L);
        });
    } finally {
        span.end();
    }
}).get();
```

However, if we modify the above code as shown below, the trace_id is propagated.

```java
TestForkJoinPool testForkJoinPool = new TestForkJoinPool(10);
Span span = tracer.nextSpan(tracer.currentSpan());

testForkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
    IntStream.range(1, 20).parallel().forEach(idx -> {
        try (SpanInScope ignored = tracer.withSpan(span)) {
            client.get(1000L);
        } finally {
            span.end();
        }
    });
}).get();
```

Unfortunately, applying SpanInScope to all existing Stream API code as mentioned above has its limitations. Is there a way to inject SpanInScope with minimal modifications to the existing Stream API code?

Thank you.

propagate the trace_id within the Java Stream API in Spring Cloud Zipkin.